# Bootstrap 3 RWD two columns to one column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two columns in one row like a

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
 <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="form-row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-6">
   </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

And it's look fine on full screen but at rwd and small width rows are broken...

**Screens:** 
http://s4.postimg.org/m0zht42wr/Zrzut_ekranu_2015_08_11_o_13_02_57.png

http://s2.postimg.org/vsujeo1uv/Zrzut_ekranu_2015_08_11_o_13_03_13.png

Comment: What is form-row? It's not a native Bootstrap class

Comment: I have no idea, Im working on not my project :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might solve it, might not:

Always add the xs size. if it is supposed to be col-12 add it.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```